# combining html link anchor with css hover

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, hover, anchor

In order to further my CSS knowledge I've been attempting this, but I'm not even sure it's possible.

I have a list of 50 links, 1 per line going down the page. There is very little vertical padding/margin between each link. Each link has been assigned an individual HTML `id`, e.g.

```
<a id="test" href="temp.html">blaghblagh</a>
```

so that visiting http://example.com/temp.html#test will change the page focus to the specific link `id`.

What I'm wanting is when a temp.html#test url is visited, the `#test` id link anchor will cause the link to "stand out" by placing padding/margin around the link.

I've been trying to combine it with `a:hover` and all kinds of stuff but to no avail. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: About security issues related to `:visited` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Privacy_and_the_:visited_selector

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `:target` pseudo selector:

```
a:target {
    padding-left: 20px;
    color: red;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dfsq/QuFHp/

> The :target pseudo selector in CSS matches when the hash in the URL and the id of an element are the same. (http://css-tricks.com/on-target/)

IE supports it starting from version 8. If you need to support older browsers you have to use javascript:

```
var hash = location.hash;
if (hash) {
    document.getElementById(hash.replace('#', '')).className = 'active';
}
```

Comment: this is exactly what I needed. thank you so much for the prompt response.

Answer (score 1):

There's a [`:visited` selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#the-link-pseudo-classes-link-and-visited) specific to anchor tags:

```
a:visited {
    padding:10px; /* Whichever values you wish to use. */
    margin:10px;
}
```

Comment: This isn't relevant to the page URL though. This will continue to build up visited links rather than 1 standing out (unless the user clears their browser history after each page load).

Comment: Oh I see. The question didn't make that very clear. I just assumed that all visited links should stand out.

Answer (score 0):

The selector you're looking for is `:visited`:

```
a:visited {
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
    /* or whatever you want, really */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done with pure CSS, but it *is* achievable with Javascript/jQuery.

Shameless plug, but I [wrote an article](http://curtistimson.co.uk/js/reading-url-hashtag-values/) on how to achieve this which you might find useful.

http://curtistimson.co.uk/js/reading-url-hashtag-values/

```
if (window.location.hash){
      var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1); //gets id in URL
      $("#" + hash).css("padding", "10px"); //applies padding to that element
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try. `a:visited{ color: red; }`

Find out more about [Pseudo-Classes small documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp)

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can do this normally with CSS. You would have to add a jQuery function which checks to see if there is an ID appended to the URL and if so add a class to that link.

Where are you going wrong with a:hover? Post some code and I'll update my answer to get that working.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote considering the clarity of the question.